# How to check App slicing feature in iOS without uploading it to Appstore

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios9, app-thinning

I am working on App slicing feature and set all images in asset, i need to check that feature without uploading on Appstore.

Is that possible? is there any way by which we can get .IPA file and check it's size or resources.

Comment: Are you discussion for `App Thinning`.

Comment: Yes. i am discussing about it. App slicing is one part of App Thinning.

Comment: the App Slicing is an AppStore-feature, you cannot test it bypassing AppStore.

Comment: Apple’s TestFlight offers the perfect solution.

Comment: @holex, thanks for your reply. so is that same for bitcode and On Demand resources ? can we test it by any other way. I want to check it before make it live.

Comment: thanks, @Rushabh. But for that i need to create app on Appstore right ?

Comment: @PJR Yes but Apple recommend to use Testflight for App thinning and ODR functionality

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to check the size of application '.ipa' file.

Just follow the following steps.

1. Open the Archives organizer (choose Organizer from the Window menu), and select the archive.
2. Click the Export button, select an export option, and click Next.
   To distribute your app to users with designated devices, select “Save for Ad Hoc Deployment.” The app will be code signed with the distribution certificate.

   To distribute your app for internal testing, select “Save for Development Deployment.” The app will be code signed with your development certificate.
3. In the dialog that appears, choose a team from the pop-up menu and click Choose.
   If necessary, Xcode creates the needed signing identity and provisioning profile for you.
4. In the Device Support dialog, choose whether to export the universal app or a variant for a specific device, and click Next.

   - If you want to run the app on any supported device, select “Export one app for all compatible devices.”
   - If you want to test all device variances, select “Export for specific devices” and choose “All compatible device variants” from the pop-up menu.
   - If you want to test a specific device variant, select “Export a thinned app for a specific device” and choose the device family from the pop-up menu.
5. In the dialog that appears, review the app, its entitlements, and the provisioning profile.
   The ad hoc provisioning profile should begin with the text XC Ad Hoc:. The team provisioning profile should begin with the text [platform] Team Provisioning Profile: [App ID]

6.Review the build options, and click Next.

7.If you request a manifest file, enter details about your web server in the “Distribution manifest information” dialog that appears.
Enter the following information:

8.Enter a filename and location for the file, and click Export.

[image]

[Refer apple document here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html)

Comment: So it means if i am uploading any app with image assets it will be sliced in iOS 9. There is not any specific things should be needed for that like we are doing for bitcode.(by checking bitcode)

Comment: @PJR, You also need to use asset catalog.

Comment: This won't get you the exact download size of the app once it's in the App Store because this IPA doesn't get encrypted in the same way that iTunes Connect encrypts it. But it will give you a rough estimate.