# iOS: Is removing the 1x images from the iOS App a good idea?

Tags: ios

Should we remove 1x images if we are no longer using non retina display? My App only supports iPhone 4 and higher.

Comment: You need 1x images when your iPhone app runs on non-retina iPads such as the iPad 2.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Given that it is not a problem for you to create the @1x assets, just add them, and the App Slicing feature of iTunesConnect/AppStore will automatically create variants for each possible device, stripping them away if they are not needed on a specific device.

Some references:

- https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html
- https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/ios-9-tutorial-series-app-thinning-and-on-demand-resources
- [Based on what, iOS App Slicing works? Is there any code or other stuff required for it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34409977/based-on-what-ios-app-slicing-works-is-there-any-code-or-other-stuff-required)